# Build and deploy node app to Openshift using Gitlab CI

Tags: node.js, openshift, gitlab-ci

Just mount a Gitlab in digitalocean to keep track of versions of some projects, but now I've read a little about Gitlab I wonder if you can set Gitlab CI so that each time you do a commit automatically make a build of application and if the build is successful can do a deploy to OpenShift.

I think my .gitlab-ci.yml should look something like this:

```
stages:
  - build
  - deploy

before_script:
  - npm install

job_build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - grunt build

job_deploy:
  stage: deploy
```

But I really do not know if this is as valid and neither tell Gitlab CI must only make a `git push` to OpenShift repository.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After much reading and searching finally found documentation about this [1], in the end I have resolved some file using the following .gitlab-ci.yml

```
stages:
  - build
  - deploy

job_build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - npm install -g grunt-cli
    - npm rebuild node-sass
    - npm install
    - grunt build

job_deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - apt-get update -yq
    - apt-get install -y ruby-dev rubygems
    - gem install dpl
    - dpl --provider=openshift --user=$OPENSHIFT_USER --password=$OPENSHIFT_PASS --domain=mydomain --app=example
  only:
    - master
```

The magic happens with a Travis library call dpl [2] that supports a lot of providers [3]

[1]http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/ci/deployment/README.html

[2]https://github.com/travis-ci/dpl

[3]https://github.com/travis-ci/dpl#supported-providers

Comment: Try to avoid running installation steps in the build and deploy stage. Instead, find Docker images with `grunt`, `nodes-sass`, `dpl` pre-installed, and use `image: <image-name>` in the build stages. This saves you a lot of time (and potentially surprises). -- Then your `script:` section can contain a single command only.